# Showing an exception when saving apex class or trigger from laptop

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I am trying to implement an apex class in my developer organization on my laptop but I'm not able to save the class. It gives me this message: `Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'undefined' at line 1 column 0`. I am able to save class from another laptop.

Refer to the screen shot below for the message.
[image]

Comment: It seems like a browser issue. Can you verify that your browser is up to date? Have you tried it in another browser?

Comment: @Lex, I have tried in all browsers in my laptop. But getting the same issue

Comment: Can you take a look at the error console in the browser, see if you get anything strange in there when you're saving?

Comment: i did n't understanding what your saying, could please explain briefly

Comment: Bro, I tried it . it works fine. i think ur browser problem.once check it

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see anything wrong. Have you tried developer console?

I almost never use your previous way or the developer console. You should download eclipse or mavens. I use Mavens btw.

For browser based IDE, this is awesome. Aside.io. If this doesn't work then I'm pretty sure all your issues are related to your browser / machine.

Good luck